# How do I remove sudo without removing ubuntu-minimal?

Tags: sudo, ubuntu-minimal

Basically I decided to use doas instead of sudo and I want to get rid of sudo because I have no use for it. However when i run 'apt remove sudo', it also wants to delete ubuntu-minumal. Is there a way of removing sudo without also removing ubuntu-minimal and/or somehow modifying ubuntu-minimal to NOT include sudo?

Answer (score 6):

`ubuntu-minimal` is a [metapackage](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages) that doesn't really contain any functionality it self; it only depends on other packages. Meta packages are used as a shortcut to select commonly used patterns to install.

You can see which packages `ubuntu-minimal` requires [in the package search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/ubuntu-minimal) or by running `apt-cache depends ubuntu-minimal`.

So in short: no, you can't remove `sudo` without either providing a empty package that claims to provide `sudo`, or remove `ubuntu-minimal`. Removing `ubuntu-minimal` will not remove any packages apart from the metapackage.

To make an empty package that claims to provide sudo, you could [look into `equivs`](https://gurpinderchahal.wordpress.com/2013/06/07/creating-empty-debian-package/)